# First order logic: Quantifiers and Scope

Tags: logic

Are these two sentences equivalent?

1. > Someone likes everyone.
2. > Everyone is liked by someone.

If yes what will be their predicate expression

Comment: What do you mean by predicate expression?

Comment: This master key fits every lock.   Every lock has a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Someone likes everyone' means that there is a person who likes every other person in the group.

'Everyone is liked by someone' means that whichever person in the group you pick, there is a person who likes him or her.

These two sentences mean completely different things.